# Java - Автоматический ввод текста на клавиатуре

Tags: java

Всем привет! Появилась проблема.

Допустим, у меня есть строка, в ней находится текст "это лучший текст лучше не придумаешь", и мне надо, что бы Java написала его на клавиатуре, т.е автоматический ввод. Как это сделать я вообще не понимаю, искал в интернете, но кроме того как просто нажимать определенные символы я не нашел. Возможно ли это как в Python, просто в параметры внести определенный текст и он сам его напишет?

Comment: Ээээээм, что, простите? Мне показалось, или Вы хотите, чтобы Java сама понажимала за Вас кнопки на клавиатуре? Что вообще значит `что бы Java написала его на клавиатуре`??

Comment: Покажите как оно сделано в python.

Comment: @Эникейщик import keyboard

keyboard.write("какой нибудь текст")

Comment: Это "не как в python", это внешний кем-то написанный модуль. Если кто-то написал похожий модуль для явы, то можно, если нет, то нет.

Comment: @Эникейщик понял, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я считаю чтоб java сама писала такое невозможно. Но возможно создать эту иллюзию. Разбить ваш текст на символы и печатать ее по одной. И добавить время отклика между командами. Чтоб создавалась эта иллюзия